DST timing is getting wrong for Egypt
The DST timing is wrong in countries where DST starts at 12 a.m., such as (Lebanon ,Cuba, Egypt). The library we're utilizing for UTC dates
Package version:
date-fns: 2.30.0,
date-fns-tz: 1.3.8.
Getting Output by the below logic
     const dstSdate = '2024-04-26';
        const dstEdate = '2024-10-31';
        // Format the date to include the UTC offset
        const sformattedDateWithOffset = format(
          zonedTimeToUtc(startOfDay(new Date(dstEdate)), serverTimezone),
          "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX"
        );

        const eformattedDateWithOffset = format(
          zonedTimeToUtc(endOfDay(new Date(dstEdate)), serverTimezone),
          "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX"
        );

DST End
Date in Egypt start : 2024-10-30T21:00:00.000Z
Date in Egypt end : 2024-10-31T21:59:59.000Z
DST Start
Date in Egypt start : 2024-04-25T21:00:00.000Z
Date in Egypt end : 2024-04-26T20:59:59.000Z
it should be
DST End
Date in Egypt start : 2024-10-30T21:00:00.000Z
Date in Egypt end : 2024-10-31T21:59:59.000Z
DST Start
Date in Egypt start : 2024-04-25T22:00:00.000Z (correct time)
Date in Egypt end : 2024-04-26T20:59:59.000Z
